# gitpython: determine the remote associated to a (tracking) branch

Tags: python, gitpython

I would like to determine the remote branch, that is associated to the current (tracking branch)

The solution, that I found is working, but it feels strange, that I have to parse the configuration to achieve what I want.

Is there any more elegant solution?

```
repo = git.Repo(path) 
branch = repo.active_branch
cfg =  branch.config_reader().config  
# hand crafting the section name in next line just seems clumsy
remote= cfg.get(f'branch "{branch.name}"', "remote")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [`git.Head.tracking_branch()`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=head.tracking_branch#git.refs.head.Head.tracking_branch) and [`git.Reference.remote_name`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=remotereference.remote_name#git.refs.reference.Reference.remote_name) can give you what you're looking for?

e.g.

```py
repo = git.Repo(path) 
branch = repo.active_branch
remote_name = branch.tracking_branch().remote_name
```

Comment: This `tracking_branch()` gives me exactly what I'm looking for and is also more intuitive to read (at least for me) than my old code